# Laravel 5.2 Controller Namespace

Tags: laravel-5, controller

how i can change my controller namespace from

```
namespace App\Http\Controller\Folder\MyController
```

to

```
namespace Folder\MyController
```

im new using laravel 5.2

Answer (score 1):

you can change `psr-4` in your composer.json file.

```
"psr-4": {
   "YourProject\\": "app/"
}
```

so, your namespace will be `namespace YourProject/Http/Controller`. don't forget to autoload your composer. I assume this is you are looking for.

Comment: i dont want using App/Http/Controller, Not change into YourProject/Http/Controller

Comment: i have controller with namespace App/Http/Controller/Folder/MyController

Comment: and i want to make shorter

Comment: then, just change your folder structure and update psr-4 in composer.json file. for reference https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4

Answer (score 0):

This is baked in to 5.2 artisan commands;

`php artisan app:name MyApp`

think you'll need to run `php artisan dump-autoload` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this in your controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Folder;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

and add this in your route,

```
Route::group(['namespace'=>'Folder'], function () {
// place your MyController route here;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1) run php artisan app:name YourNamespace
2) rename your app folder to YourNamespace
3) in your bootstrap folder create a file called application.php
4) paste this in there

```
class Application extends Illuminate\Foundation\Application {

protected $appBasePath = 'app';

public function __construct($basePath = null)
{
    $this->registerBaseBindings();

    $this->registerBaseServiceProviders();

    $this->registerCoreContainerAliases();

    if ($basePath) $this->setBasePath($basePath);
}

public function setAppPath($path) {
    // store the path in the class only
    $this->appBasePath = $path;

    // set the path in the container (using this class's path to reset it)
    return app()->__set('path', $this->path());
}

/**
 * Get the path to the application "app" directory.
 *
 * @return string
 */
 public function path()
{
    return $this->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$this->appBasePath;
}
```

}

5) save the file and open app.php 
6) and replace your application bootstrap with the following

```
// load our local application
 require __DIR__.'/application.php';

 // instaniate our application
 $app = new \Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
 );

 // set the path to match the namespace
 $app->setAppPath('YourNamespace');
```

7) Save your app.php and that's it

Hope this help you.